# Copy file if no error was encountered, else delete copied portion

Tags: cp, file-copy

I am copying a folder in Linux with plenty of files. Some of the files give me errors like this:

```
Error splicing file: Input/output error
```

The problem is that it keeps the file in the new location although it doesn't open. I would like to write a command that would simply skip the file if this type of error occurs and doesn't delete it from the new location.

My final directory should have only those files in which the error doesn't occur.

Comment: If some of the system's commands act like that (partially copied files or other junk lying around after an error) it is a serious bug, to be reported.

Comment: `rsync` will do what you want.

Comment: The question is unclear: We need to see what command you're currently using to be able to suggest a modified variant that would do what you want.